# determine if uiview is displayed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uikit

is there a possibility to determine if an uiview obj is going to be displayed. imagine: you have 2 uiviews in an uiscrollview. now you are going to switch per gesture from the first view to the second. the first view now is NOT in the viewport. now you are going to go back to the first view. and now I want to be notified that this view is in viewport, or is redisplayed. the same has to be for the second view. I have not found any callback or something like this.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What gesture? I'm guessing its a swipe. Swipe left/right to slide two views in and out of the frame right?

Comment: it must be independet from gestures. if the view goes into the viewport, I want to be notified.

Answer (score 0):

You make sure your UiViewController overrides viewWillAppear: (before it appears this method is called) or viewDidAppear: (after this method is called).

See: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:

Comment: you thats right, but the problem is, this view is a in a library which is delivered to customers. and the customers should not do such an override. I know there is a possibility to define a custome uiviewcontroller class which is going to do this and all uiviewcontrollers must inherite from it, but this is too much affort for app programmers. they should only init the uiview and define postioni. thats enough. i think this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

That depends what you mean by "switch". If one view is just scrolled out of the visible area of the scrollview, but still remains attached as a subview to it, then you may want to check if the bounds of your view overlap those of the scrollviews visible area.

You could do this by using [UIScrollView Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)'s `scrollViewDidScroll:` method to implement a check for overlaps while the user is scrolling.

If however your view is actually removed from the viewstack, then you may want to subclass UIView and implement `willMoveToSuperview:` to check if the view has been added to the scrollview again.